# Javascript function messes with jQuery code

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have problem with my javascript and jQuery. I have a HTML page contains many hidden `<div class="section">` for my glossary term purpose. With a search box using javascript to unhide the `<div class="section">` if the text matches search key.

Here is the search function. What it does is to look for the searchTerm in all the `<div class="section">`, highlight the found searchTerm and unhide the div.

```
var run = 0;                // used to cycle through colours
var colours = new Array(7);
colours[0] = 'yellow';
colours[1] = 'orange';
colours[2] = '#FF6666';
colours[3] = 'pink';
colours[4] = 'lightblue';
colours[5] = 'turquoise';
colours[6] = 'lightgreen';

function findall(searchTerm) {

if (!searchTerm) { 
    window.alert('Please enter a word or phrase to search for'); 
    return false; 
}
if(searchTerm.length <2)
{
    alert("Keyword is too short, try again");
    return false;
}

var source = document.getElementsByClassName("section");
var count = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < source.length; i++)
{

    if(source[i].innerHTML.search(searchTerm) > 0)
    {
        var temp = new RegExp("("+searchTerm+")","gi");
        count = count + source[i].innerHTML.match(temp).length;
        source[i].style.display ='block';

        var src_str = source[i].innerHTML;
        var pattern = new RegExp("("+searchTerm+")", "gim");

        src_str = src_str.replace(pattern, "<span style='background-color:"+colours[run]+"'>$1</span>");

        source[i].innerHTML = src_str;  

    }
}
run++;  
}
```

And I have a jQuery code to unhide another div on the same page when user click on the hyperlink within the `<div class="section">`

```
$(".termselector").click(function () {
    var termID= $(this).attr('name');
    var containerID= '#term' + termID;      
    $(containerID).show();
});
```

All the codes are in the same script.js file. My problem is if I don't use the search function, the above jQuery works fine, but after using the search function, the jQuery code doesn't work anymore. I tried to place them in 2 separate js files but the problem remained. Please help

Comment: console log? antyhing else that could be useful?

Comment: Try reproducing your issue here http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: `source[i].innerHTML = src_str;` You seem to be destroying the content and replacing it with new content. Destroy a node and replace it with a new one, and naturally its handler will no longer work

Comment: ...and WRT all the `.innerHTML` searching and replacing, the DOM exists for a reason. Why not use it instead of pretending like it's a big string of HTML?

Comment: @KevinOpdenKamp nothing in the console

Comment: @cookie monster
how do I highlight a string without doing what I did there???

Comment: Is there any way I can highlight the found text without destroying the handler ??

Comment: It would be a good idea to go through some tutorials to learn how the DOM API works. In your case, if there' only one `span` element in each `section`, then use `querySelector` to select it, and then change its `style` property. `source[i].querySelector("span").style.backgroundColor = colors[run];` Or if there are other `span` elements, then give the one you want a class, and do `.querySelector("span.myClass")`.

Comment: @cookiemonster there isn't any span in the section class. I only wrap a span around the string that matches search keyword.

Comment: Oh, I misread the code. There are other questions that deal with how to wrap individual words in an element. You should be able to find a solution.

Comment: @cookiemonster I found a workaround which works for me, I wrap the text of the hyperlink in a span and only highlight the text, without replacing the hyperlink itself. So the handler doesn't get changed.